# How do I get my Jersey 2 Endpoints to eagerly initialize on startup?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I am porting some code from Jersey 1.x and my implementation of various Health Check endpoints relies on all the `@Singleton` endpoint resources being initialized at start up so as to be able to detect which checks to do.

In Jersey 2.0 - whatever I do I can't seem to get my resource endpoints to initialise at start up and they are only constructed+initialized when each one is accessed for the first time.

I guess I could initialise them myself in the `Application` class but I'd rather use the package scanning!

Does anyone have any idea if there is some config option that will tell Jersey 2 to eagerly initialise all resource endpoints that it finds during package scanning?

Or some HK2 annotation or trick?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> "Or some HK2 annotation or trick?"

You can use HK2's [Immediate Scope](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/extensibility.html#immediate-scope). Just annotate the resource class with [`@Immediate`](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Immediate.html) (which acts like `@Singleton`, so you can get rid of that), then enable the immediate scope on the `ServiceLocator`. An example:

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities;
...

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public JerseyApplication(ServiceLocator locator) {
        ServiceLocatorUtilities.enableImmediateScope(locator);
        packages("thepackages.to.scan");
    }
}
```

---

#### UPDATE

Based on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29289245/2587435), if you need to explicitly instantiate the `ResourceConfig`, as in the case of the linked question, you can create a `Feature` and register the feature, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29292733/2587435)

#### UPDATE 2

Please see [related issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2979)

#### UPDATE 3

Looks like Immediate scope memory leak issue previously linked to has been resolved in version 2.22.1