# @Immediate annotation use in Jersey2

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have a similar issue to the one raised here: [How do I get my Jersey 2 Endpoints to eagerly initialize on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114602/how-do-i-get-my-jersey-2-endpoints-to-eagerly-initialize-on-startup)

But slightly further down the line.  I can get my resource immediately loaded, but when I try to use it by calling the REST url, I get the following stack trace.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an active context for org.glassfish.hk2.api.Immediate
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: While attempting to create a service for      
SystemDescriptor(
implementation=com.service.MyResource
contracts={com.service.MyResource}
scope=org.glassfish.hk2.api.Immediate
qualifiers={}
descriptorType=CLASS
descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
metadata=
rank=0
loader=null
proxiable=null
proxyForSameScope=null
analysisName=null
id=150
locatorId=0
identityHashCode=1249600275
reified=true) in scope org.glassfish.hk2.api.Immediate an error occured while   locating the context
```

My TResource class is annotated thus:

```
@Immediate
@Path("/test/v1")
public class TResource {
```

My Grizzly based server is setup like so:

```
ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
            .packages(true,
                    "com.mystuff"
              )        
            .property(ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, "true");

    HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(base_uri), rc);

    ApplicationHandler handler = new ApplicationHandler(rc);
    ServiceLocatorUtilities.enableImmediateScope(handler.getServiceLocator());
```

Any guidance would be most appreciated !
cheers,
Phil

Answer (score 14):

One way to get a handle on the `ServiceLocator` is to implement a [`Feature`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Feature.html).

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities;

public class ImmediateFeature implements Feature {

    @Inject
    public ImmediateFeature(ServiceLocator locator) {
        ServiceLocatorUtilities.enableImmediateScope(locator);            
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        return true;
    }  
}
```

Then just register the `Feature`

```
ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("jersey.hk2.test");
rc.register(ImmediateFeature.class);
```

I've tested this and it works fine

Comment: Thanks ! That does indeed solve the issue.  Much appreciated!. Phil