# Java Jersey construct class at bind time

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, singleton, hk2

I'm working on some Java Jersey stuff and would like to do the following;

I've got a class called SerialSubject:

```
public class SerialSubject{
    private final SomeDatabase someDatabase;

    @Inject
    public SerialSubject(SomeDatabase someDatabase){
        this.someDatabase = someDatabase;
        initializeSerial();
    }

    InitializeSerial(){
        SerialConfig config = SomeDatabase.getConfig();
        //Open a Serial connection using this config
    }
}
```

I'm binding this class using an AbstractBinder and register it to my ResourceConfig as per usual.

```
bind(SerialSubject.class).to(SerialSubject.class).in(Singleton.class)
```

All good and well, the dependency is resolved when requested by a resource and the serial connection is opened.

Now the caveat: I want to open the Serial connection at startup time. Is there any way to instantiate the class immediately? Constructing it manually won't do, as the database(which is already bound to ioc) is needed to retrieve the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Immediate`](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Immediate.html) scope

> Immediate is a scope that operates like `javax.inject.Singleton` scope, except that instances are created as soon as their corresponding `Descriptor`s are added. When the corresponding `Descriptor` is removed from the locator the `Immediate` scope service is destroyed. In particular `Immediate` scope services are not destroyed if the `ServiceHandle.destroy()` method is called. Care should be taken with the services injected into an immediate service, as they also become virtual immediate services

```
bind(SerialSubject.class).to(SerialSubject.class).in(Immediate.class)
```

You will also need to configure the `ServiceLocator` to enable the immediate scope.

```
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public JerseyApplication(ServiceLocator locator) {
        ServiceLocatorUtilities.enableImmediateScope(locator);
    }
}
```

**See also:**

- [How do I get my Jersey 2 Endpoints to eagerly initialize on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28114602/2587435)